# Handling multiple WM_USER messages (or achieving the same result)

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-messages

I have a `WidgetController` class that controls multiple widgets (motors as it turns out, but it could be practically anything). It has a companion UI class `WidgetControllerUI` to do UI things representing the multiple widgets.

I would like to send messages such as `WM_USER + 1000 + N` from the `WidgetController` instance to the `WidgetControllerUI` instance to indicate that something has occurred with widget `N`. That part is easy:

```
// Somewhere inside WidgetController:
pWidgetUI->PostMessage( WM_USER + 1000 + N );
```

But how can I direct all these (contiguous) messages into a single message handler in my `WidgetControllerUI` class? On the surface, `ON_COMMAND_RANGE`, `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE` and `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` do not appear suited. Are they? Is there a more elegant mechanism, perhaps not using Windows messages at all?

Comment: I'd just use a single message and pass N in wparam or lparam, but I don't know if that would make it any easier with MFC.

Comment: I would not even bother with the 'N', just pass the widget instance in wParam or lParam.

Comment: Ha! All these years using PostMessage() with default arguments... I never actually noticed you can send optional parameters with it! D'Oh! Obvious answer - thanks!

Comment: That's what you get when you dive into MFC without understanding the Windows API. I'd also raise the question whether `WM_USER + x` is the correct range of messages. Are the recipients window classes you registered yourself, calling [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx)?

Comment: No - it is a windows dialog created by the MFC class wizard to which I want to send a messages (or range of messages) representing "widget N has changed". Registering messages or classes seemed overkill to me, but if there is something I've missed, please offer an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @Ross suggested, you can pass you 'N' into PostMessage() as one of the [lParam, wParam] arguments.  They are pointer-size on both 32 and 64 bit OS.

Note that your shenanigans with N are often unnecessary.  With dynamically-allocated objects, (like GUI elements usually are since they must outlive the function that created them), it's common to pass in the object instance pointer as one of the parameters.  The other can be used, (eg. as as an enum), to command the message-handler function, (eg with a switch/case), to perform some specific action with the instance passed.

You will need a bit of casting either way, but I've never had any problem with such mechanisms.

The only possible issue is that the instance may not exist by the time the message is received, eg. because the user has deleted it by 'normal' human interaction with the GUI.  How likely this is, and how you might guard against it, is app-specific.